KQL - How to clear whitespace in string array
I am creating a workbook in Azure where i am using KQL query and i have to dynamically pass resource groups values in the query from parameter.
From Parameter, resourcegroups are coming like
 {ResourceGroups:label} ==> rg-abc-prod-westus, rg-xyz-ttt-westus
. There is a whitespace after , and before rg-xyz-ttt-westus
When i am using
let resourceGroupList = split("{ResourceGroups:label}",",")
the result is coming as ["rg-abc-prod-westus"," rg-xyz-ttt-westus"]
For the second resource group there is a whitespace between " and rg-xyz-ttt-westus.
Therefore in query, it is taking only first resource group.
I want like
["rg-abc-prod-westus","rg-xyz-ttt-westus"]


Did the below answer worked @Mohit Dhamija?

You can use replace_regex() like below kql query:
let tst = replace_regex("rg-abc-prod-westus, rg-xyz-ttt-westus",@"\s","");
let resourceGroupList = split(tst,",");
print(resourceGroupList)

Output:

Fiddle.
Here, I have directly given array value, you can use the parameter for it and use the rest of function.

fyi, the :label formatter for multi-value parameters returns all the content of the parameter as a single string as it is displayed in the UI instead of an array of values, so it could be like "a, b, c, +3 more" instead of "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" like the real value is.
it would be better to use the raw value directly, like
let resourceGroups = todynamic([{ResourceGroups}]);

so that resourceGroups is a real array of selected values, then you shouldn't have to do any regex/etc and have a valid KQL array object you can use like
| where whatatever in (resourceGroups)
(and you can do other things like | where array_length(resourceGroups) == 0 or... to handle cases where nothing is selected, etc
